# Error in setting a value in sql server trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I'm trying to make a trigger that checks which staff member have the least amount of assigned tasks, before adding the task, and assign it to that member.
What I came up with was something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsteadOfInsert ON helpCase
INSTEAD OF Insert
AS
declare 
 @helpCaseId int,
 @problemTypeId int,
 @problemDescribtion varchar(200) ,
 @staffId int,
 @problemSolution varchar(200),
 @operatingSystemTypeId int,
 @applicationTypeId int,
 @helpCaseOpenDate datetime,
 @helpCaseclosedDate datetime;

select @helpCaseId=i.helpCaseId from inserted i;
select @problemTypeId=i.problemTypeId from inserted i;
select @problemDescribtion=i.problemDescribtion from inserted i;

set @staffId = (select Min(ID) frOM (SELECT staffId as ID, COUNT (*) FROM helpCase where helpCaseClosedDate IS NULL GROUP BY staffId)) ;

select @problemSolution=i.problemSolution from inserted i;
select @operatingSystemTypeId=i.operatingSystemTypeId from inserted i;

select @helpCaseOpenDate=i.helpCaseOpenDate from inserted i;
select @helpCaseclosedDate=i.helpCaseclosedDate from inserted i;



BEGIN 

Insert into helpCase values(@helpCaseId,@problemTypeId,@problemDescribtion,@staffId,@problemSolution,@operatingSystemTypeId,@helpCaseOpenDate,@helpCaseclosedDate);
END
```

but I'm getting the following error for the line that I'm setting the value of `@staffId` in :

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting AS,ID or QOUTED_ID.
```

Any idea what should I do!?

Comment: why are you selecting data from inserted in multiple select statements?

Comment: Because it's the only way I know.
I would very much appreciate it if you can lead me to a better way.

Comment: my answer leads you to a better way. When we use 'Set' to assign a value to a variable it allow you one per statement, where as 'Select' allow you to assign value to multiple variables with a single statement using ','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a derived table in the from clause without an alias.

This will give you the same error:

```
select *
from (
     select *
     from YourTable
     );
```

Add an alias to the derived table.

```
select *
from (
     select *
     from YourTable
     ) as T;
```

Note: Your trigger will fail if you insert more than one row at a time. The trigger is executed once per insert statement, not once per row.

Comment: Thank you,
I've tried it but it gave me the following error:
 `No column was specified for column 2 of't'.`

Comment: @Abdo20293 Yes, and that is taken care of in the same way. `COUNT (*) as TheCount`. Why do you get the count anyway? You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: I've made a mistake, I should put the count in the Min function.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm new here, can you help me with the [on hold] thing?
I didn't understand what's wrong with the question.
How can I make it right?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Abdo20293 Don't worry about it. The question will still be around. The question to one of my most upvoted answers on SO is closed as not a real question. [Declare variable in table valued function [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661505/declare-variable-in-table-valued-function/6661756#6661756). It is still there collecting votes and shows up in searches.

Answer (score 1):

As Mikael already replied 'Add an alias to the derived table.' or Use below optimized version of your script.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsteadOfInsert ON helpCase
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
    BEGIN 

    Declare @staffId int

    SELECT  @staffId =  MIN(staffId)
              FROM  helpCase
              WHERE helpCaseClosedDate IS NULL
              GROUP BY staffId


        INSERT  INTO helpCase
                SELECT  i.helpCaseId,
                        i.problemTypeId,
                        i.problemDescribtion,
                        @staffId,
                        i.problemSolution,
                        i.operatingSystemTypeId,
                        i.helpCaseOpenDate,
                        i.helpCaseclosedDate
                FROM    INSERTED i ;


    END
```